# Can't install git on Ubuntu 22.04 - unmet dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, git, dependencies

I had git installed on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, but recently it became uninstalled somehow. `git --version` displays `Command 'git' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install git`.

Trying to install again, I receive this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
git : Depends: git-man (< 1:2.39.1-.) but 1:2.39.2-0ppa1~ubuntu22.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have run `sudo apt update` `sudo apt upgrade` and ensured nothing is held back. `sudo apt install -f` also did not work.

Edit: `apt policy` displays:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main armhf Packages
     release o=code stable,a=stable,n=stable,l=code stable,c=main,b=armhf
     origin packages.microsoft.com
 500 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main arm64 Packages
     release o=code stable,a=stable,n=stable,l=code stable,c=main,b=arm64
     origin packages.microsoft.com
 500 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main amd64 Packages
     release o=code stable,a=stable,n=stable,l=code stable,c=main,b=amd64
     origin packages.microsoft.com
 500 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google LLC,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.google.com
 500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=LP-PPA-git-core,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Git stable releases,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpadcontent.net
 500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=LP-PPA-git-core,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Git stable releases,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpadcontent.net
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-backports,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-backports,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-backports,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-backports,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-updates,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=Ubuntu,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
```

Edit 2: Removing the existing PPAs via Software & Updates worked. https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages https://itsfoss.com/held-broken-packages-error/

Comment: One of the PPAs configured on your system is causing the problem; please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt policy`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I had added ppa:git-core/ppa at some point and forgotten about it.  You have it as well in your apt policy.

```
apt policy |grep git

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

 500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=LP-PPA-git-core,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Git stable releases,c=main,b=i386apt policy |grep git

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

 500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=LP-PPA-git-core,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Git stable releases,c=main,b=i386
```

Simplest solution I found is to [remove the PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/310/236635) until the issue is resolved by the maintainer.

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
```

It does however leave me with a slightly older version of git.  If anyone finds out a way to resolve the dependency please do share it.  Hopefully the package maintainer does it soon :)